# Arnold on Homogeneous Linear Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In this section, Arnold formulates the equation that we know as the homogeneous linear equation. My question is why the term $\partial a/\partial X$ vanishes when linearisation is done?

[image: Arnold]

Completing the steps for linearisation around the point $(p, 0)$, we get

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X}\Big|_{(p,0)} &= a(X,Y)\Big|_{(p,0)} \\
&=  a(p, 0) + \frac{\partial a}{\partial X}\Big|_{(p,0)}(X-p) + \frac{\partial a}{\partial Y}\Big|_{(p,0)}(Y) \\
&= \frac{\partial a}{\partial X}\Big|_{(p,0)}(X-p) + f(X)\Big|_{(p,0)}Y
\end{align}
$$

because $a(p, 0) = 0$ and re-writing $\frac{\partial a}{\partial Y} = f(X)$

Now, why is $\frac{\partial a}{\partial X} = 0$? How does $a(X+T, Y) = a(X, T)$ translate to this fact?

Using the limit definition of differentiation, we have

$$
\lim _{\Delta X \to 0} \frac{a(X+\Delta X, 0) - a(X, 0)}{\Delta X}
$$

but we can't just say that $a(X+\Delta X) = 0$ right? (because it only happens at periods of T)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised $a(X + \Delta X) = 0$ and $a(X, 0) = 0$ simply because of the fact that the $a(X, 0) = 0$ is given. The fact $a(X+T, Y) = a(X, Y)$ should have no utility here.